# Mongoose v6 findOne() returns null when querying an object field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to migrate from Mongoose v5 to v6. I have one collection with fields of type object -

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const teams = {
  identifier: {
    type: {
      id: String,
      team: String
    }
  }
};

const teamsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(teams, {
  timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt', updatedAt: 'updatedAt' }
});

const TeamsModel = mongoose.model('teams', teamsSchema);
export default TeamsModel;
```

During testing findOne() is returning null when querying object fields like this

```js
// METHOD 1
const doc = await TeamsModel.findOne({
  identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test' }
});
```

but it works as expected when querying like this

```js
// METHOD 2
const doc = await TeamsModel.findOne({
  "identifier.id":  '1',
  "identifier.team":  'test',
});
```

Since Method 1 use to work fine in v5, wondering if something changed & whether there is some way to keep using the older query in v6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

From [migrating_to_6](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#typepojotomixed) guide:

> Schema paths declared with `type: { name: String }` become single nested subdocs in Mongoose 6, as opposed to Mixed in Mongoose 5.

I will use the below code to create a document to the `teams` collection.

```js
const team = new Team({ identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test' } })
await team.save();
```

The debug logs using *"mongoose": "^5.13.17"*:

```bash
Mongoose: teams.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("6465ef70de3bc5e612d6ab86"), identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test' }, createdAt: new Date("Thu, 18 May 2023 09:27:12 GMT"), updatedAt: new Date("Thu, 18 May 2023 09:27:12 GMT"), __v: 0}, { session: null })
Mongoose: teams.findOne({ identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test' } }, { projection: {} })
identifier is Mixed type?  true
doc1:  {
  _id: 6465ef70de3bc5e612d6ab86,
  identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test' },
  createdAt: 2023-05-18T09:27:12.688Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-18T09:27:12.688Z,
  __v: 0
}
Mongoose: teams.findOne({ 'identifier.id': '1', 'identifier.team': 'test' }, { projection: {} })
doc2:  {
  _id: 6465ef70de3bc5e612d6ab86,
  identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test' },
  createdAt: 2023-05-18T09:27:12.688Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-18T09:27:12.688Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

The `identifier` field is mixed type, **there is no `_id`** field.

The debug logs using *"mongoose": "^6.11.1"*:

```bash
Mongoose: teams.insertOne({ identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test', _id: new ObjectId("6465f26ce5eb26573b8b0b69") }, _id: new ObjectId("6465f26ce5eb26573b8b0b68"), createdAt: new Date("Thu, 18 May 2023 09:39:56 GMT"), updatedAt: new Date("Thu, 18 May 2023 09:39:56 GMT"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: teams.findOne({ identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test', _id: new ObjectId("6465f26ce5eb26573b8b0b6b") }}, {})
identifier is Mixed type?  false
doc1:  null
Mongoose: teams.findOne({ 'identifier.id': '1', 'identifier.team': 'test' }, {})
doc2:  {
  _id: new ObjectId("6465f26ce5eb26573b8b0b68"),
  identifier: {
    id: '1',
    team: 'test',
    _id: new ObjectId("6465f26ce5eb26573b8b0b69")
  },
  createdAt: 2023-05-18T09:39:56.371Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-18T09:39:56.371Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

The `identifier` is **not** mixed type anymore, it's a **subdocument** with `_id` field.

If you use below query:

```js
const doc1 = await Team.findOne({ identifier: { id: '1', team: 'test' } });
```

It [Match an Embedded/Nested Document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document)

> Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an exact match of the specified `<value>` document, including the field order.

Let above said, `identifier` field is a subdocument with a `_id` field when using *mongoose 6.x*. `{ id: '1', team: 'test' }` document does **not** match the `{ id: '1', team: 'test', _id: 'xxxx' }` subdocument exactly. That's why the query result is `null`.

It will work when using *mongoose 5.x* since it does match the value of the `identifier` field exactly. Because it's a mixed type.

But it's an exact match when using *mongoose 5.x* since there is no `_id` field.

We can run a query by [Specify Equality Match on a Nested Field](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field) use the [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-dot-notation)

```js
const doc2 = await Team.findOne({
  "identifier.id": '1',
  "identifier.team": 'test',
});
console.log('doc2: ', doc2);
```

If you want to create a mixed type for the `identifier` field, use any one of below:

```js
const teamsSchema = new Schema({ identifier: {} });
const teamsSchema = new Schema({ identifier: Object });
const teamsSchema = new Schema({ identifier: Schema.Types.Mixed });
const teamsSchema = new Schema({ identifier: mongoose.Mixed });
```